# How to add variable into class tag in html?

Tags: html, css

In below example, `i` is a variable. We want to make `div`'s background color automatically changes as the `i`'value changes. How to add variable into `class` tag in html?

.js

```
var i = 0;
```

`i` will be changed after some processing.

.html

```
<div class="bgcolor+i"></div>
```

.css

```
.bgcolor0{
   backgorund: red
}
.bgcolor1{
   background: green
}
...
```

Comment: [You can see an example on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734374/how-to-set-a-javascript-variable-in-attribute-of-a-html-tag)

Answer (score -1):

You want to add the class name dynamically. Just write the class name in this way

```
<div class=`bgcolor-${i}`></div>
```

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't work

Comment: Then please visit this link
https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding

Answer (score -1):

you can do it in JavaScript - get the element by it's id and set the css class in code. (you need to give that div id for that)

@justinas gave you a link with a sample how to do it -
[change element class with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)